# Image to play sound onclick

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I'm trying to make a song play when I click on an image. everytime I do it using the solutions on the here Either the image doesn't show, the audio doesn't play, or both. I don't understand what my issue is and could use any help.

My HTML
`

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>#F7D64B</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"                 
href="https://csshake.surge.sh/csshake.min.css">
</head>

<body>
<script>
var audio = new Audio('Music/song.wav');
    function myAudioFunction
<script>

<center>

<audio id="audio" src="Music/song.wav"></audio>
<a onclick="document.getElementById("audio").play();">
    <img src="assets/a.png" width=550 height=550 class="shake-slow shake-    
constant">
</a>
</center>

</body>

<footer>
<!-- art by @woun404-->
<!-- #F7D64B -->
</footer>
</html>`
```

Comment: What errors are you getting in the console of your browser's developer tools?

Comment: @j08691 Oddly Enough none, the console is blank.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example:

```js
document.getElementById('play').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById('audio').play();
});
```

```html
<audio id="audio" src="http://www.soundboard.com/handler/DownLoadTrack.ashx?cliptitle=Never+Gonna+Give+You+Up-+Original&filename=mz/Mzg1ODMxNTIzMzg1ODM3_JzthsfvUY24.MP3"></audio>

<a href="#" id="play">
    <img src="assets/a.png" width=550 height=550 class="shake-slow shake-    
constant">
</a>
```

Comment: When I try to do this It doesn't play the audio but the image does show up. The console says: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at index.html:15"

Comment: @X3Friends: Really? Plays just fine for me. Are you sure you added id `play` to your anchor element?

Answer (score 1):

Using JavaScript only would look like this:

```
<body>  
<center>

<audio id="audio" src="Music/song.wav"></audio>
<img id="img" src="assets/a.png" width=550 height=550 class="shake-slow shake-    
constant">
</center>
<script>
document.getElementById("img").addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("audio").play();
});
<script>
</body>
```

It is advised to use JavaScript for big projects since it works way faster.

Comment: When I try to do this It doesn't play the audio but the image does show up. The console says: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null at index.html:15"

Comment: my bad. `<script>` should be loaded as least item befor `</body>`

Comment: I have the scripts at the top after the `<body>` tag, It still gives me the same error.

Comment: I found the issue, Solved it now