# How do you make a sound play when a hyperlinked image/text is clicked (still taking you to the hyperlinked webpage)

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I'm doing an SDD assessment and I'm making a website kind of game. It will be a choose your own adventure game and I'm trying to incorporate JavaScript. I have 3 buttons that will take the user to different pages and I would like each of the buttons to make a sound when they're clicked. The buttons are text with a sword image above them, so I'd like a sword sound to play. However, I'm not experienced with JavaScript. I found some code for it at https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/286059/play-sound-when-a-link-is-clicked
but it means nothing to me cause I don't know how to use it. Would someone be able to explain to me what it means and how to adapt it to my HTML and CSS?

Here's my HTML code

```html
<html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <title>SDD Minor Project Code</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/js" href="script.js">
            </head>

            <body>
                <div class="home_sword">
                    <a href="https://trinket.io/html/c11627b947?outputOnly=true&runMode=autorun">
                    <img id="home_button_img" src="button_underline_sword_left.png">
                    <h2><i>Home</i></h2> 
                    </a>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <img class="left_shield" src="shield_title_bookend.png">
                  <h1 class="story_title"><i>Viking Attack</i></h1>
                  <img class="right_shield" src="shield_title_bookend.png">
                </div>
                  <img class="scroll" src="story_scroll.png">
                <div class="narrative">
                  <p>Hello, World!</p>
                </div>
        
            </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49539491/image-to-play-sound-onclick

Answer (score 0):

Here's an exemple of what i made on one of my projects when i was learning JavaScript

```
<script>
function soundAlarm() {
          let amount = 3; // count of sound you want here is set on 3 but you can change it as much you want
          let audio = new Audio("Timer_Sound_Effect.mp3"); //here variable for the src of the sound

          function playSound() {     // function that plays the sound 
              audio.pause();
              audio.currentTime = 0;
              audio.play();
          }

          for (let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {   // loop to play as many times you asked in "let amount "
            setTimeout(playSound, 1200 * i);  // 1200 = 1200 mseconds between each times the sound plays.
          }

  }
</script>
```

In html just put as attribute to play it:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
            <div>
              <img class="left_shield" src="shield_title_bookend.png" onclick="soundAlarm()"> <!-- function called on the click to play the sound-->
              <h1 class="story_title"><i>Viking Attack</i></h1>
              <img class="right_shield" src="shield_title_bookend.png" onclick="soundAlarm()"> <!-- function called on the click to play the sound-->
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's your code with the modifications :)  :

```
  <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>SDD Minor Project Code</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/js" href="script.js">
        </head>

        <body>
            <div class="home_sword">
                <a href="https://trinket.io/html/c11627b947?outputOnly=true&runMode=autorun">
                <img id="home_button_img" src="button_underline_sword_left.png"> 
                <h2><i>Home</i></h2> 
                </a>
              </a>
            </div>
                </a>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div>
              <img class="left_shield" src="shield_title_bookend.png" onclick="soundAlarm()"> <!-- function called on the click to play the sound-->
              <h1 class="story_title"><i>Viking Attack</i></h1>
              <img class="right_shield" src="shield_title_bookend.png" onclick="soundAlarm()"> <!-- function called on the click to play the sound-->
            </div>
              <img class="scroll" src="story_scroll.png">
            <div class="narrative">
              <p>Hello, World!</p>
            </div>
    
        </body>
        <script>
function soundAlarm() {
          let amount = 3; // count of sound you want here is set on 3 but you can change it as much you want
          let audio = new Audio("Timer_Sound_Effect.mp3"); //here variable for the src of the sound, change it by the path of your file, or directly by your file name if in same folder.

          function playSound() {     // function that plays the sound 
              audio.pause();
              audio.currentTime = 0;
              audio.play();
          }

          for (let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {   // loop to play as many times you asked in "let amount "
            setTimeout(playSound, 1200 * i);  // 1200 = 1200 mseconds between each times the sound plays.
          }

  }
    </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: I see that you have in your <title> a link to a script.js, you can paste the full code in <script></script> in it if you want, it would work the same :)